# Monero GUI wallet blocks wont sync and now my funds are missing

Tags: daemon, wallet

I have had monero GUI for about 6 months time and i have used it a bit for sending XMR.
A few days ago my GUI didnt want to finalize synch with DAEMON. it kept loading and "crashing" and when it finally said daemon is synchronized the wallet blocks never synched. i have tried the last 3 days without any luck. i have gotten quite close, but then it "crashes" and restarts the synching process.

After reading online i tried to turn of the firewall anti virus without luck and i tried to log off the acc. and log back on

the problem now is.

after i logged back on, my funds have disapeared. and it still cant fully connect to daemon.
At first i thought i might have logged in to a different acc. so i retraced the steps to when i first got the account and found my first transaction to the GUI wallet from binance.

On binance it says the same address as the acc i am currently logged into. but on GUI it doesnt show any funds nor any previous transactions.

cant really find a solutoion to my problem anywhere so hope there is anyone here that can help!

Comment: Which `Wallet mode` are you using? You can check it on the `Settings` page. Also, are you using the GUI in conjunction with a Ledger or Trezor device? Which operating system are you using? And which specific version of the GUI.

Comment: I am using GUI v0.16.0.2 (Qt 5.12.2)

Comment: just switched to advanced mode to try with a remote node from xmr.to that i found on moneroworld. i am not using it with a device and i am using windows 10

Comment: Does it properly connect with the remote node? What is the status of the bars in the left bottom?

Comment: well its a bit different. sometimes it succesfully connects and one bar is completely orange. Sometimes its not fully orange and sometimes it just says waiting for daemons to sync and nothing happens.

Last night i got it to full orange and i was waiting for wallet blocks which took forever. and today when i woke up everything had gone back to zero

last night

Comment: And this is in `Advanced mode` right? Can you double check the `Wallet mode` on the `Settings` page?

Comment: yes, advanced mode

Comment: can it be that the wallet needs to be fully synched before i can see my funds? right now it just says 0.000000 and 0 transactions

Comment: Yes, the wallet needs to be fully synced in order to properly reflect the balance. What is the status of the status bars in the left bottom? Also, on the `Settings` page, is the wallet set to `Local node` or `Remote node`?

Comment: the status bar changes constantly. at the moment the GUI is running 24h,  but it will never be fully sync. 
As i am typing this it says:
top  "waiting for wallet to sync"
bottom "Daemon block remaining 772690"

sometimes it can say "daemon sync"
and "connected" but the wallet blocks will never be full.

Right now its on "Local node"
i tried "remote node" with different nodes from monerowold, but without any success.

Comment: Can you perhaps try these steps: 1. Exit the Monero software. 2. Delete `data.mdb` from your computer (it should be located in `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb` - note that, by default, this directory is hidden. However, if you use Windows Explorer you should be able to navigate to it) 3. Open the Monero GUI, but do not open your wallet. Instead, go back to the main menu. 4. Select `Simple mode` as `Wallet mode`. 5. Reopen your wallet via the `Open a wallet from file` option. Does it work properly now?

Comment: when i came home from work last night, everything was fine and everything was fully synced. When i woke up today, it was the same problem. So i tried to delete data.mdb file, but still no success.

Comment: when looking on my log i can see this

2020-07-19 22:05:30.261 [RPC0] ERROR daemon.rpc src/rpc/core_rpc_server.h:101 [127.0.0.1:49859 INC] Failed to on_get_blocks()

Comment: Did you also switch to `Simple mode` as I suggested?

Comment: yes i did. 
my wallet just fully synced again for about 10 min and then it just stopped synching and started all over

Comment: Can you switch to `Advanced mode` and set a custom node? The page basically has to look like this -> https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-GUI-guide/blob/master/monero-GUI-guide.md#remote-node

Comment: i will try again, tried it already with a node from xmr.to without success
will try with opennode.xmr-tw.org at port 18089 this time.

Comment: nothing changed.

Comment: Do you use custom AV (AntiVirus) software on this system? It may be interfering, hence.

Comment: no, i have the windows defender AV and i made sure all monerod and GUI pass threw with firewall and defender

Comment: Are there any error messages in the log? And, to be clear, your wallet is set to `Advanced` mode and `Remote node` correct?

Comment: no, now i am back to simple mode and trying to connect. On simple mode i can connect to deamon, but still having trouble with the syncing part. 2 days ago i was again fully connected, but only for a short time, then as if it starts to re circuit and cant connect again. 

when i open monerod.exe manually i get this error message before it closes down
 "2020-08-01 09:31:45.658 F Error starting server: Failed to bind IPv4 (set to required)"

Comment: Can you perhaps try to restore the wallet from the 25 word mnemonic seed and set the remote node (i.e. `node.xmr.to:18081`) in the wizard? Make sure to choose `Advanced mode`, then you should be able to set it on this page: https://github.com/monero-ecosystem/monero-GUI-guide/blob/master/monero-GUI-guide.md#daemon-settings-advanced-mode (make sure box 4 is checked).